Processing JSON post request on express. Followed all suggestions but empty request body
I am using the following to post to my express server from a React App:
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3100/api', { 
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  }, 
//  body: { "user":"1", "cmd":"Send NFT"},
  body: JSON.stringify({ user: 1, cmd:"Send NFT"}),
          })

I tried to use either one of the body formats
And on the nodejs side with version 4.21.1 express:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3100;

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
})

app.post('/api', (request, response) => {

  console.log("User: " + JSON.stringify(request.body) );
  
  if (request.body.user == 1) response.send(JSON.stringify({ user: 1, cmd: request.body.cmd}));
  else if (request.body.user == 2) response.send(JSON.stringify({user: 2, cmd: "Info from 1"})); 
})
  
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})

I get "User: {}"
I'm thinking this is a result of CORB protection, but as far as I can tell, the principal ways to help properly evade unwanted filtering is to properly label the content type, in this case,
headers: {'Content-type':'application/json'}

I had to mark the fetch as "mode: no-cors" even though the transfer is from localhost to localhost.

Sorry, I'm answering my own question. I found a solution and it's one I hadn't seen before in any of the posts related to this problem, perhaps because it's on express verion 4.21.1:
Simply change the following:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3100;

app.use(express.json());

To this:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors')
const port = 3100;

app.use(cors())

app.use(express.json());

you must load the cors pakage with
npm install cors

and see:
https://github.com/expressjs/cors?tab=readme-ov-file#enabling-cors-pre-flight

for more information.
With that I could remove the mode: no-cors line from then origin fetch.
